# Is it possible to reference a COM DLL without registering itself?

Tags: c#, dll, com

I have activated COM registration free DLL when deploying the application. In addition, I have set the Properties->Linker->Register Output to NO in my build process. However now my application which references the DLL no longer builds because it cannot find the reference. So my question is that is it possible to build the application that references the DLL without registering the dll?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a legacy COM in a C# application or rather expose C# dll as COM to a legacy environment?

Comment: The C# project references the output of the COM project (they are in the same solution) and now its not building because it cannot find the COM (reg free). So is there anyway to make it reg-free but still be referenced in another project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left no breadcrumbs to guess why registration is required to *build* your code.  This is not normally necessary.  One random guess is that you are using the *Isolated* property for a reference in a C# project for a COM component written in C++.   Which is a very nice feature, it automatically generates the manifest entries so the program can run reg-free.

But those manifest entries need to come from *somewhere* if you don't write them yourself.  Which is the registry if you use the *Isolated* property.  Chicken-and-egg problem here, you have to register it so it can run unregistered :)

Keep in mind that you use reg-free COM on the *user's* machine, it isn't important on your dev machine.

Comment: I wrote the manifest myself :) The manifest allows the user to run reg-free. I then toggled the "register output" in the linker property to No for the COM project. The C# project references the output of the COM project (they are in the same solution) and now its not building because it cannot find the COM (reg free). So is there anyway to make it reg-free but still be referenced in another project?

Comment: "it cannot find the COM (reg free)" is not a C# compiler error message I've ever seen.  You do need to tell us *exactly* what you see.  Btw, you are ignoring the last sentence in my post.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Yes I read your last sentence but I feel that if I can find the root cause of the issue, it would benefit me! The error I see is Error 41 The type or namespace name 'XXXLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  XXXLib is the COM dll I am reference, which is built by another project within the same solution.  Since I do not register the output of the COM project, I cannot find the reference in add reference -> COM. Is there anyway to get it working?

Comment: Look in the .csproj file with a text editor, Notepad is fine.  Check if you see a `<COMReference>` with a Guid element.  That requires it to be registered.  You avoid that by running Tlbimp.exe explicitly.

Comment: Yes.. you are correct. I see     <COMReference Include="VTC_COMLib">
      <Guid>{F78327D5-BBDC-296B-8DF1-CCDCFC63CCD9}</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>


Does this mean I need to add a post build process to run tlbimp on the COM DLL manually?  Thanks for your advice I truly appreciate it!
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Isolated>False</Isolated>
    </COMReference>